# Why would Xend try to restore a deleted domain/VM?

Tags: xen, domu

I have a domain 'host10' that no longer exists on the system. The config file was renamed, the configuration changed to point to a different .img, and the image name was renamed as well.

I've done this multiple times, in the end I renamed and moved 10 domU's. This is the ONLY one that continuously tries to restore when the system boots.

How can I prevent xend from trying to restore a deleted VM? I removed the symlink out of /etc/xen/auto, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xen makes a file, called a save file, in my case (CentOS 5.6) it was in `/var/lib/xen/save`. I did an rm on that file, and now it no longer attempts to restore this deleted VM.

Comment: Perhaps you should disable this function. We had here the problem that there was an old snapshot of an mashine in this folder. And after a long time we made a reboot and they restored the old snapshot. After that the filesystem in the disk was broken.

Perhaps it was only a bug but i don't know.